# regeneratorRuntime is not defined when trying to use puppeteer js for PDF generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, puppeteer

I am trying to generate a PDF using React SSR and Express, when ever i am adding the code for getting the pdf generation in puppeteer i am getting

```
referenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at /Users/rahsinwb/Personal/Myworks/react-ssr/src/server.js:50:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rahsinwb/Personal/Myworks/react-
```

The thing i found is there is some error in the babel preset but as per links [https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/717] i have modified the babel settings but still i get the error.

I was previously trying it with the same route and later separated it but still i get the same error.

This is what i am trying

```
app.get( "/data", ( req, res ) => { // i want the pdf gen logic to be part of this route only
    const context = { };
    const store = createStore( );

    store.dispatch( initializeSession( ) );

    const dataRequirements =
        routes
            .filter( route => matchPath( req.url, route ) ) // filter matching paths
            .map( route => route.component ) // map to components
            .filter( comp => comp.serverFetch ) // check if components have data requirement
            .map( comp => store.dispatch( comp.serverFetch( ) ) ); // dispatch data requirement

        Promise.all( dataRequirements ).then( ( ) => {
            const jsx = (
                <ReduxProvider store={ store }>
                    <StaticRouter context={ context } location={ req.url }>
                        <Layout />
                    </StaticRouter>
                </ReduxProvider>
            );
            const reactDom = renderToString( jsx );
            const reduxState = store.getState( );
            const helmetData = Helmet.renderStatic( );
            const htmlData = htmlTemplate( reactDom, reduxState, helmetData );

     (async () => { // logic for in the same route
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage()


            //2. Create PDF from static HTML
            await page.setContent(htmlData);
            await page.pdf({ path: 'html.pdf', format: 'A4' })

            await browser.close()} )()

            res.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" } );
            res.end( htmlData );
        } );
    } );

    app.get( "/data1", ( req, res ) => {
        (async () => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage()
            await page.goto('http://localhost:2048/data')
            const buffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'})
            res.type('application/pdf')
            res.send(buffer)
            browser.close()
        })()
    })
```

**Update** 
I am using this code base as my boilerplate and this is the package json i used just installed puppetteer js on top of this

https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/package.json

This is the babel rc file

https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/.babelrc

Comment: The problem is caused by your packages and/or babel setup. Include those in your question too.

Comment: @WillJenkins just added